# Django handling foreign keys to multiple models

Tags: python, django

```
class Product(models.Model)
class InventoryItem(models.Model)
class Warehouse(models.Model)
class Store(models.Model)
class Office(models.Model)
class Lab(models.Model)

(... and many more)

class ProductImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
class InventoryItemImage(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    inventory_item = models.ForeignKey(InventoryItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
(... and many more)
```

I'm trying to add the ability to attach multiple images to a model. The problem is, there are more than 10 models and adding every `<modelname>Image` does not quite suit me. I need to query and post-process images so I'd really prefer one model holding entire images info.

I tried searching and there were a few options.

1. Create every `<modelname>Image` model for `<modelname>`.

This seems quite not right.

2. Use Django's `GenericForeignKey`.

I thought of this, but after reading this [blog article](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/avoid-django-genericforeignkey/) I'm not so sure.

3. One `Image` model, and `ManyToManyField` in all models.

Promising, but not so sure. Also Django admin is not properly showing image upload fields.

4. Create dummy model, models foreignkey to it and `Image` model foreignkeys to it too.

Seems overly complicated.

What would be the right way to do this? Any new suggestions or guides welcome!

Comment: Can an image be used by more than one product?

Comment: @engin_ipek No, it cannot. Only one item to image.

Comment: so the relation is not many_to_many, is it? It is one_to_many. In other words a product could have many images, but an image could only be owned by a certain product, right?

Comment: @engin_ipek Yes. models need to have many images, but an image sticks to a specific model pk.

Comment: You could use inheritance, although that is not per se a good idea.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thought about it, but the models are scattered across many apps.

Comment: "but the models are scattered across many apps" does not matter much. If you have common views, models or serializers; you should have a "core" app with just generic or abstract versions of your views/models/serializers and all other apps should inherit from them.

Comment: @flobin201: the fact that the "subclasses" are scattered over multiple apps is not relevant. These are after all just tables, and the Django ORM can do the bookkeeping for that.

Comment: I vote for the second variant.